# Error While loading project in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, devexpress

> Error 109 'Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v14.1,
>   Version=14.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or
>   one of its dependencies. Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004003 (E_POINTER))'

I use to work on VS2008 previously, but recently I have moved from VS2008 to VS2012. Everything is working good, but whenever I add Devexpress Control(Grid View) in my project, I am getting this error message.

I have searched for this error on Google, and everytime I have found the below mentioned link but it didn't solved my problem.

Link I use to get from Google : https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18620

Please help.

Comment: What's target framework specified for your project? It should be 4+.

Comment: I haven't specified target framework. My project was build in VS2008 and I guess we can't specify target framework in VS2008. Now, I have migrated to VS2012. where do I need to specify target framework??

Comment: In the project properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: Thank you @Gosha_Fighten. It really solved my problem...

Comment: Welcome! I've moved my comments to an answer so that you can mark it as a solution to close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your project is targeted to a .NET version prior to 4. Version 14.1 of DevExpress components requires .NET 4+. Change your .NET version in the project [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx).